# Triggering imperative animations using React Refs

Tags: reactjs, css-animations, js-scrollintoview

from the documentation, there's this use case for Refs:

`Triggering imperative animations.`

Can someone offer an example on how this should be done please? I'm trying to bring the user attention to a div after having scrolled it into view using its Ref and I think this would be an ideal use case, maybe?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See [`Refs and the DOM`](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html), [`EventTarget.addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener), and [`Element.getBoundingClientRect()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect) for more info.

```js
// Imperative Animation
class ImperativeAnimation extends React.Component {

  // State.
  state = {background: '#fff'}

  // Render.
  render = () => (
    <div ref={this.divRef} style={{height: '200vh', background: this.state.background}}>
      Scroll to turn background papayawhip.
    </div>
  )
  
  // Did Mount.
  componentDidMount() {
    window.addEventListener('scroll', this.onScroll)
  }
  
  // Div Ref.
  divRef = React.createRef()
  
  // On Scroll
  onScroll = event => {
    const div = this.divRef.current
    const {y} = div.getBoundingClientRect()
    if (y <= 0) this.setState({background: 'papayawhip'})
    else this.setState({background: '#fff'})
  }
  
}

// Mount.
ReactDOM.render(<ImperativeAnimation/>, document.querySelector('#root'))
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think imperative animation means define animation by javascript

> https://anvaka.github.io/sj/compare/

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).